# Is multer-gridFS-storage still usable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I'm trying to look for a way to upload files directly from the frontend into mongodb's gridFS. In all the tutorials I came across, people are using multer-gridFS to upload directly to the databse. However, they are all rather old tutorials and when I look at the readme.md of Multer-gridFS on npm, it says that it's compatible with mongodb version 2 and 3. Does that mean this package is deprecated and no longer useful? The code they provide also doesn't seem to work for me. I haven't found a better way to upload files to the database, since the mongodb official documentation recommends this code snippet for uploading:

```
fs.createReadStream('./myFile').
     pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('myFile', {
         chunkSizeBytes: 1048576,
         metadata: { field: 'myField', value: 'myValue' }
     })
```

which implies that I need the path to myFile, but when users upload files, we obviously don't have access to the absolute path. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to upload files to the gridfs without having to first download the file to a predetermined folder and using the path to that folder to store into gridFS?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that multer-gridfs-storage is abandoned. (and it has been throwing deprecation warnings that come from the mongo driver since mongo 3.x, so I doubt it works for mongo 7.x) If you still want to use multer, but upload directly to mongodb.GridFSBucket without using multer-gridfs-storage, you can do the following

routes.js

```
   app.post("/bslite/document/upload", ctlr.upload.bind(ctlr));
```

mycontroller.js

```
const mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const { GridFSBucket } = require("mongodb");
const multer = require("multer");

class DocumentController extends BasicController {
  #client;
  #db;
  #bucket;
  #upload;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor() {
    super(collectionNames.DOCUMENTS, DOCUMENT);  ///
    var mongoConf = getConfigData(MONGO_CONFIG);  // replace with your own configuration or hardcode the database below

    (async () => {
      this.#client = await mongo.connect(getConnectionUrl(), getConnectionOptions());  // genConnectionUrl() and getConnectionOptions() are my own functions - substitute your values
      this.#db = this.#client.db(mongoConf.database);
      this.#bucket = new GridFSBucket(this.#db, { bucketName: "doc" });
    })();

    this.#upload = multer();
  }

   ...

  async upload(req, res) {
    this.#upload.single("file")(req, res, () => {
      const { body, user } = req;
      const {
       x, y, z
      } = body;
      
      // business logic, if any, goes here

      // example metadata - not required
      const metadata = {
        encrypted: false,
        mimeType: req.file.mimetype,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        z: z,
        createdDate: new Date(),
        lastModifiedDate: new Date(),
        modifiedByUsers: [user._id],
        description: description || "",
        createdBy: user && user._id ? new ObjectID(user._id) : null,
      };

      var buffer = req.file.buffer;
      var stream = this.#bucket.openUploadStream(req.file.originalname, {metadata: metadata, contentType: req.file.mimetype});
      stream.write(buffer);
      stream.on("finish", (file) => {
        logger.debug("Received Request to upload document " + req.file.originalname + " from user " + req.user.sid);
        res.json({ document: file.filename });
      });
    
      stream.end();
    });
  }

   ...
}
```

If you implement something like the above, you should be able to remove the multer-gridfs-storage package safely.